# How do I get the JSON result from Amadeus API (Kotlin Android)

Tags: android, json, api, kotlin, amadeus

I am trying to use the [Amadeus Offers Search API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference) with the following code:

```
when (val flightOffers = amadeus.shopping.flightOffersSearch.get(
        originLocationCode = "MDZ",
        destinationLocationCode = "MAD",
        departureDate = LocalDate.parse("2020-11-11").toString(),
        adults = 2,
        max = 1
    )) {
        is ApiResult.Success -> {
            if (flightOffers.succeeded) {
                println("RESULT SUCCEEDED")
                println(flightOffers.data)
            }
            else
            {
                println("RESULT DIDN'T SUCCEEDED")
            }
        }
        is ApiResult.Error -> {
            println("RESULT ERROR")
        }
    }
```

And if I compile that the logcat output is as follows:

```
I/System.out: RESULT SUCCEEDED
```

Which makes me think that flightOffers.data is empty.

However if I try this code:

```
val flightOffers = amadeus.shopping.flightOffersSearch.get(
        originLocationCode = "MDZ",
        destinationLocationCode = "MAD",
        departureDate = LocalDate.parse("2020-11-11").toString(),
        adults = 2,
        max = 1
    )
    println("AMADEUS: $flightOffers")
```

I get the following output:

```
I/System.out: AMADEUS: Success(meta=Meta(count=1, links={self=https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=MDZ&destinationLocationCode=MAD&departureDate=2020-11-11&adults=2&max=1}), data=[FlightOfferSearch(type=flight-offer, id=1, source=GDS, instantTicketingRequired=false, nonHomogeneous=false, oneWay=false, lastTicketingDate=2020-05-03, numberOfBookableSeats=7, itineraries=[Itinerary(duration=PT18H, segments=[SearchSegment(departure=AirportInfo(iataCode=MDZ, terminal=null, at=2020-11-11T07:10:00), arrival=AirportInfo(iataCode=AEP, terminal=null, at=2020-11-11T08:45:00), carrierCode=AR, number=1403, aircraft=Aircraft(code=738), duration=PT1H35M, id=1, numberOfStops=0, blacklistedInEU=false, co2Emissions=null), SearchSegment(departure=AirportInfo(iataCode=EZE, terminal=A, at=2020-11-11T13:25:00), arrival=AirportInfo(iataCode=MAD, terminal=1, at=2020-11-12T05:10:00), carrierCode=UX, number=42, aircraft=Aircraft(code=789), duration=PT11H45M, id=2, numberOfStops=0, blacklistedInEU=false, co2Emissions=null)])], price=SearchPrice(currency=EUR, total=1151.26, base=510.0, fees=[Fee(amount=0.0, type=SUPPLIER), Fee(amount=0.0, type=TICKETING)], grandTotal=1151.26), pricingOptions=PricingOptions(includedCheckedBagsOnly=true, fareType=[PUBLISHED], corporateCodes=null, refundableFare=false, noRestrictionFare=false, noPenaltyFare=false), validatingAirlineCodes=[UX], travelerPricings=[TravelerPricing(travelerId=1, fareOption=STANDARD, travelerType=ADULT, price=SearchPrice(currency=EUR, total=575.63, base=255.0, fees=null, grandTotal=0.0), fareDetailsBySegment=[FareDetailsBySegment(segmentId=1, cabin=ECONOMY, fareBasis=ZYYOPO, segmentClass=Q, includedCheckedBags=IncludedCheckedBags(weight=0, weightUnit=null)), FareDetailsBySegment(segmentId=2, cabin=ECONOMY, fareBasis=ZYYOPO, segmentClass=Z, includedCheckedBags=IncludedCheckedBags(weight=0, weightUnit=null))]), TravelerPricing(travelerId=2, fareOption=STANDARD, travelerType=ADULT, price=SearchPrice(currency=EUR, total=575.63, base=255.0, fees=null, grandTotal=0.0), fareDetailsBySegment=[FareDetailsBySegment(segmentId=1, cabin=ECONOMY, fareBasis=ZYYOPO, segmentClass=Q, includedCheckedBags=IncludedCheckedBags(weight=0, weightUnit=null)), FareDetailsBySegment(segmentId=2, cabin=ECONOMY, fareBasis=ZYYOPO, segmentClass=Z, includedCheckedBags=IncludedCheckedBags(weight=0, weightUnit=null))])])], dictionaries={locations={MAD={cityCode=MAD, countryCode=ES}, EZE={cityCode=BUE, countryCode=AR}, MDZ={cityCode=MDZ, countryCode=AR}, AEP={cityCode=BUE, countryCode=AR}}, aircraft={789=BOEING 787-9, 738=BOEING 737-800}, currencies={EUR=EURO}, carriers={AR=AEROLINEAS ARGENTINAS, UX=AIR EUROPA}})
```

Which means that the API is returning a JSON but then I can't use flightOffers with gson to pass this data to a DataClass because flightOffers is a ApiResult> and I don't know how to use that. According to their [library docs](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-android) it should be done like I did it in the first try.

I appreciate all the help and advice I can get. This is my first Android App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice to see that we have a new Android developer in the community !

So first, in Android you should avoid using println, instead you should use `Log.d/e/w/i`, this method will print your result in android logcat.

For what I see you successfully setup your project and where able to make query from the sdk.

In the android sdk, every `get()` will give you a correct data object and not just JSON. You don't have to take care of parsing the answer. The thing you have in your `flightOffers.data` is in fact a `List<FlightOfferSearch>` that you can use right away !

Comment: Thank  you! This fixed my issue! Also regarding Logs, is the Timber library used? Because I remember it from the udacity Android Dev Course but, I don't know if it's recommended by other users.

Comment: Timber is also a great library to log, I use it in a lot of projects !